# Error when posting data into SQL database from form

Tags: php, mysql, database, post, pdo

I'm trying to post data into an SQL database from a form. 
I really don't understand what I am missing...
I tried several things I managed to make it work once but the form was only adding the id and it was leaving the other fields blank. Now it doesn't work at all.

My form is this

```
<form action ="addOutfit.php" method="post"> 

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" placeholder="" value="">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" id="description" value=""></textarea>
</div>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
</form>
```

and my code is this

```
 <?php
  require("pdo.php"); 
  $_POST['title'] = "";
  $_POST['description'] = "";


  if (isset($_POST["submit"])){ 

  $title = $_POST['title'];
  $description = $_POST['description'];



  $sql = "INSERT INTO outfit (title, description) 
    VALUES('$title', '$description')";
  $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

 $statement->execute([
    'title' => $title,
    'description' => $description
]);
}; 
?>
```

Comment: quite a few things wrong and this `if (isset($_POST["submit"])){...}` nothing will fire up in there. *Think "name" attributes* here.

Comment: And you don't have placeholders to bind anything.

Comment: All your input fields are missing `name` attributes. `id` isn't used for form submissions.

Comment: Try removing :
$_POST['title'] = "";
  $_POST['description'] = "";
from your code.

Comment: Always a good idea to dump the POST super global, if you are head scratching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changes:-

1. provide `name` attribute to all your input fields.
2. either provide `name and value` attribute to button, or check with `POST` data values of input field (more preferable).

So your code will be like below:-

```
<form action ="addOutfit.php" method="post"> 

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "title" id="title" value="">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="description">Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name= "description" id="description" value=""></textarea>
</div>

     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Send</button>
</form>


<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); // check all type of error
ini_set('display_errors',1); // display those error
require("pdo.php"); 
if (isset($_POST['title']) && isset($_POST['description'])){  // check actual input data not submit button

    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];
    $sql = "INSERT INTO outfit (title, description) VALUES('$title', '$description')";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $statement->execute(['title' => $title,'description' => $description]);
}
?>
```

**Note:- checking db connectivity is your responsibility. I don't know what code you have in `"pdo.php"`. Good-luck.**

Comment: Thanks a lot it works just fine now! I am a beginner I don't really understand the error functions but I will check on the PHP manual for that... Otherwise in order to escape inputs would you recommend to use the htmlspecialchars function or the mysqli_real_escape_string function?

Comment: Yes you can use those, and why -ve marking . Please tell me why you did that (the person who did it?).

Comment: you can use `mysqli_real_escape_string` to prevent from `SQL Injection`